# Is it possible to create new log file for each iteration?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Can anyone tel me how to create the new log file for each iteration.??

Log properties:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=.\\LogFile.html

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=Log File
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.LocationInfo=true
```

What is changes i need to do in this properties file ???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please explain your scenario ? What iteration you want.Logger settings can be implemented to application or Application Server

Comment: please define iteration

Comment: For each execution or iteration of my application i need to create the new log file

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming with each iteration you mean each time the program runs. If that's the case then the following should help:

- In your log4j.properties file add the following line:

  ```
  appender.file.Append = false
  appender.file.fileName=../logs/${sys:logfilename}.log
  ```

  This makes sure that each new runs creates a new file and doesn't append to the previous log and '${sys:logfilename}' takes care of picking up the value against the system variable called logfilename which we need to define in our code before defining the logger (next point).
- Define the logfilename system variable before importing the logger. Here I am appending date and time with each new log file:

  ```
    String dateTimeNow = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
    System.setProperty("logfilename", "mylogfile_"+dateTimeNow);
    logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
  ```